# How to build icu data dll in windows?

Tags: windows, dll, msbuild, timezone, icu

I have tried numerous resources and I haven't really seen a proper command or way to build the icu data dll in windows.

So I have tried -

```
msbuild source\allinone\allinone.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64
```

It builds the icudt62.dll but it had reduced data set.
I tried `pkgdata` with `dll` mode and `runConfigureICU` with  `--with-data-packaging=library` and none of them seem to want to work properly in building the icudt.dll file (as in the command fails miserably with lot of errors).

I tried building from Visual studio and also in command line like this -

```
msbuild source\allinone\allinone.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /t:MakeData
```

These two work and it builds the icudata dll fully but I am not sure this is the right approach since it seems to build tests also.

Has someone tried building/packaging the entire icu data (mainly dates and timezone mappings) from windows in command line? How do we build the icu data into a dll?

TIA.